# pzmap or pzplot color handle for multiple plots

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

I am plotting a closed loop poles of a systems using **pzmap.m** or **pzplot.m** whichever you prefer. I want to see the movement of poles and zeros as I change a variable depicted by **L**.

The function does not have a direct handle for color. In the example you can just choose the standard colors but cannot give your own color. Since I have to plot multiple times on the same figure, I create a handle for every iteration in a *for* loop and use **findobj** to set the color of the curve. To get the colors I want to have a *colorbar*. So I use **jet** to get the color distribution for my graph. But the market size stays the same and I have one ugly looking figure.

MWE:

```
cb=jet(10);
s=tf('s');
L_array=5:5:50;

figure; hold on;
for i=1:length(L_array)
    L=L_array(i);
    G=((58.2+11.7*L)*s^2*25^2+(3996.8 + 815.7*L)*s*25+815.7*25^2)/(s^2*(s^2*25^2+126.9*s*25+(3996.8+1.9*25^2)));
    CL=feedback(G,1);
    pzmap(CL);
    h = findobj(gcf,'type','point'); set(h,'markers',12,'color',cb(i,:));
    clear L G CL h
end
grid;
c=colorbar
c.Label.String = 'L'
```

If you run it you'll see that the size doesn't change and graph looks crazy with the y axis on either side labelled with ticks. I want a proper *colorbar* from blue to red and the colors distributed properly but can't get it after multiple tries. If I can get less cluttering that would be helpful too.

Comment: I have run your code: If I don't understand wrong, you just want to color the "time", so each time you plot something it will have some different color. What I can see in my computer (Matlab 2014b) is that the line `h=findobj(...` actually has no effect, and that is your problem. `h` is empty.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out...but I cannot understand for the life of me what property name to use. Using 'type' 'point' returns empty. If I use h=findobj(gcf,'marker', 'o') or h=findobj('marker','x') then I have something but setting the command set(h,'MarkerSize',12,'MarkerEdgeColor',=cb(i,:)) makes everything of the same color...I know its a problem of handle but cant figure it out

Comment: I am writing a response now, I got it.

Comment: kudos :) thanks for the effort man...cheers

Comment: check my answer, and consider accpeting it if it helped ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are several problems in your code

- `h = findobj(gcf,'type','point');` The things drawn in the screen are actually of type `'line'`!
- Every iteration, you catch **all the points**, modify them an dimdediately after **delete** the properties with clear.

Additionally, `h = findobj(gcf,'type','line');` will not return a single thing, but a set of them, so you need to index through it to set the properties. My modified code working looks like this:

```
clear;clc
cb=parula(10);
s=tf('s');
L_array=5:5:50;

figure; hold on;
for i=1:length(L_array)
    L=L_array(i);
    G=((58.2+11.7*L)*s^2*25^2+(3996.8 + 815.7*L)*s*25+815.7*25^2)/(s^2*(s^2*25^2+126.9*s*25+(3996.8+1.9*25^2)));
    CL=feedback(G,1);
    pzmap(CL);

end

% lets do this in the end!

% you will have length(L_array)*2 +1 items in h
 h = findobj(gca,'type','line'); 
for jj=2:length(h)
        set(h(jj),'MarkerSize',12,'Color',cb(floor(jj/2),:));
end
grid;

colormap(parula);   % I am using parula, you can use jet, but I discourage it
c=colorbar;
```

[image]

PD: there are tons of reasons not to use `jet`!! Use perceptually uniform colormaps please!

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot. But for me the colorbar is like how it is in your case but the markers are from blue to red and not blue to yellow? Secondly, I tried using colormap but it just doesn't shown anything!

Comment: Also there is not way in pzoptions to remove the numbering along the vertical axis on the right

Comment: Ok, so I didnt realized about the colobar not changing. I just updated the code. @Zero . The same way you are getting the line property, you can get the "Ytick" property and set it to zero. That will make them dissapear I think.

Comment: What is cb in the code for you?? And if I may ask why do you use the floor?

Comment: If I am unclear, I mean if assign colors using cb, how come you use parula? That is why in my case unless I extract colors from parula and assign those colors it is not going to change! and I don't know how to do it!

Comment: @Zero sorry I had formating problems, now you can see the full code. `cb` is the same as in your code. As you will have 21 `h` in your case and `jj` will iterate though `20` of them. However, they go in pairs, as they are `zeros` `poles` `zeros` `poles` `zeros` `poles` ..... . So we want the first pair in one color, teh second in another. The floor makes a fancy way of doing that

Comment: @Zero you can use `jet` if you want. I am philosophically again `jet` becaus it is not Perceptually uniform". But that has nothing to do with your problem. If you are interested, [this webpage explains it](https://bids.github.io/colormap/)

Comment: Dude fantastic job...I struggled with it for 2 hours looking and reading on the net...cheers

Comment: Hey if it is possible can you tell me how to remove the right side ticks? I just cant figure it out!