# pzplots - Yticks and Colorbar Issue

Tags: matlab, plot

I am using **pzmap** to plot system poles and zeros for different values of **L**. But the plot has additional YTick Labels at the right side which I cannot see in the axes properties. Also, I do not have the handle corresponding to constant damping gridlines whose color and properties I would like to change.

MWE

```
clear;clc
cb=parula(10);
s=tf('s');
L_array=5:5:50;

figure; hold on;
for i=1:length(L_array)
    L=L_array(i);
    G=((58.2+11.7*L)*s^2*25^2+(3996.8 + 815.7*L)*s*25+815.7*25^2)/(s^2*(s^2*25^2+126.9*s*25+(3996.8+1.9*25^2)));
    CL=feedback(G,1);
    pzmap(CL);
end
h = findobj(gca,'type','line'); 
for jj=2:length(h)
    set(h(jj),'MarkerSize',12,'Color',cb(floor(jj/2),:));
end
grid;

colormap(parula);
c=colorbar;
```

Also the colorbar is inverted i.e. Blue corresponds to larger **L** and vice versa. I would like to have it inverted! Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the way,  the colormap is not inverted. Add pause(0.2);drawnow; after pzmap in the loop and you will see that the first points drawn are the ones that later are blue.

Comment: Yeah you are right but when the colorbar sets in at the end, the colors get reversed...

Comment: I got the reverse order thing worked out by simply using flipud() on jet for the assignement operation...but still can't find a handle for YTick. Also I cannot find the handle for the constant damping lines

Comment: change `cb(floor(jj/2),:)` for  `cb(end-floor(jj/2)+1,:)` in the code to reverse colors

Comment: The additional ticks are inserted by "grid". Still don't know how to remove them

Comment: Hey if you look at your answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40001798/pzmap-or-pzplot-color-handle-for-multiple-plots?noredirect=1, the damping factors are all wrong! Why is that?

Comment: What do you mean? How are they wrong? How should they be?

Comment: Sorry my bad...didn't look at the numbers on y axis

Comment: No worries ;) I can't figure out how to remove the Ylabels, as they are not shown in the axes, as you say. A workaround would be not activating the grid, but I udnerstand that you may want that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any handle to the desired objects in the plot. However, I have some additional insights. The grid corresponding to **pzmap** has, inherently, an **sgrid**. The handles of this grid do not show up in the **gca** properties. So you cannot do anything about it. Even the **pzoptions** does not enable you to modify those settings. Additionally, the additional *Y-Ticks* correspond to lines of constant natural frequencies.

Alternatively, it is better to use the **sgrid** command directly. To choose the constant damping lines,

```
z = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1];
```

To remove the additional *Y-Ticks*,

```
wn = [];
```

Now, use **sgrid** and **grid** command to get whatever you want.

```
sgrid(z,wn);
grid;
```

I can't still change any properties of the grid lines associated with **sgrid** but it still improves the look of the plot. The question is still open to investigation.